# Сокрытия и показ элемента

Tags: javascript

Есть код, кнопка прячет мой текст. Как сделать чтобы эта кнопка не только прятала текст, но и показывала назад.

HTML

```
<button id="hide">Сховати текст</button>
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

CSS

```
document.getElementById('hide').onclick = function (){
document.getElementById('text').hidden = true;}
```

Comment: Слева от ответов на Вашие вопросы есть знак "галочка". Он там для Вас.

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.getElementById('hide').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('text').hidden = !document.getElementById('text').hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="hide">Сховати текст</button>
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо), последний вопрос. А как это сделать через условие if?

Comment: @DmitryChernyak А почему бы Вам самому не попробовать сделать это через условие `if`?

Comment: Я понял, большое искреннее, и так помогли мне)